# (JAVA) Como tratar exception com o spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exceção

Na minha model eu declarei esse código para ser único.

`@Column(unique=true, name = "codigo")`
`private long codigo;`

Na hora que ela é exibida na api e eu informo codigos igual para dois funcionários aparece a
mensagem de erro, como posso trata-la ?

Tentei fazer assim :

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ConstraintViolationException extends RuntimeException{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public ConstraintViolationException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
```

Mas não funcionou, o que falta no meu código ? Uso java e spring boot.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um ExceptionHandler com a anotação @ControllerAdvice, como nesse exemplo aqui:

https://github.com/isaiastavares/ifood-microservices/blob/master/ifood-suggestion-server/src/main/java/br/com/ifood/exception/CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java